# Google Compute Engine gives error from when creating instance with existing boot and data disk

Tags: google-compute-engine

I originally created an instance with a persistent boot and data disk.  I wanted to test that should something happen to an instance, I could just recreate one with the same boot and data disk and it would run as normal.

However, I'm getting this error when creating the instance from the developer console:

`Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[1].source': 'site-data'. Must be a URL to a valid Compute resource of the correct type.`

The only thing I'm doing differently is setting the boot disk to the previous site-boot disk rather than a new image, and attaching the site-data disk in read/write.

Comment: What command are you using to attach the 'site-data' disk or how exactly are you trying to do this? Just based on the error, it seems that it's asking for the URL to the 'site-data' resource (disk) and not the name, which is what you might be trying to use. Hard to say, not enough info.

Comment: Had the same problem. I cloned the BOOT and SECONDARY disks of a machine I already have to clone the machine entirely. Used the console.developers web interface 'new instance' option, put the BOOT SOURCE disk as the BOOT disk I just cloned and put an additional disk as the SECONDARY disk I just cloned too. Gave me this error in the console.developers 'Activities' window.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cloned' a disk? Are you referring to a 'snapshot'? If so, once you have the snapshot, you have to use it to create a new disk from it and then you can attach the disk to an instance.

Comment: I was trying to create the instance right from the Developers Console, not using the SDK or anything.  Another weird issue though.  Since it wasn't working, I tried deleting the instance and both disks and starting all over, however it gave me the same error even with everything new.  It seems the issue is with attaching a second disk during instance creation.

To fix it, I just created an instance with only the boot disk attached, then after it was created I went to its settings and attached the data disk from there.  That worked no problem.  Should I post this as an answer?

Comment: To add to my last comment about how it was fixed, this also solved my main goal of being able to just restart the server should something happen to the instance.  From what I can tell, if your instance is deleted for example, you can just create a new instance with the existing boot disk attached to it and attach the data disk after it's created (you will have to run safe_format_and_mount again to mount the data disk).  All should work as normal, given there's no file corruption or something wrong with the OS itself.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try again -- it looks like their web-based Developer Console was broken for a few days bracketing the time you put your question in.  It seems to work correctly now.

I also received this error when attempting to create an instance that included an additional Persistent Disk.  Creating an instance with only the boot drive worked fine, but attempting to create an instance with any additional disk (including a new, empty disk) resulted in the same error you reported above.

I used the "Need Help?" link at the bottom left of the 'Create a new instance' web form to report the problem yesterday (10/21/14).  Although I did not receive any kind of reply (I have not paid for any support options), the issue was resolved within 24 hours.  I am now able to successfully create instances with additional Persistent Disks again.